# Java: How to make a string in Unicode Normal Form C

Tags: java, csv, nfc

I use opencsv parser to parse some csv files with data. So i get these warnings that some lines are not in Unicode Normal Form C, resulting in a wrong delimitation. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the ICU4J library, or http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html in Java 1.6 or newer.